# Installer not showing up any dialogue box

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, windows-7-x64, wix3.6

I'm using WiX 3.6 Installer for creating a custom Installer.

Here is my code for installer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="Installer" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Installer" UpgradeCode="b678de18-2e38-44d5-a686-9e923f8c565e">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Installer" Level="1">
            <!--<ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />-->
        </Feature>

    </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <!--<UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />-->
    <UI>
      <Dialog Id="InstallDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] Setup" NoMinimize="yes">
        <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes">
          <Text>{\DlgTitleFont}Ready to Install</Text>
        </Control>
        <Control Id="Install" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17"
    Default="yes" Text="Install">
          <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" />
        </Control>
      </Dialog>
      <InstallUISequence>
        <Show Dialog="InstallDlg" After="ExecuteAction" />
      </InstallUISequence>
    </UI>
  </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Installer">

        </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
            <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
                <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
            <!-- </Component> -->
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents"/>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

The problem is that the installer is not showing up atleast a single dialogue box.

It is showing like this and disappearing after few seconds.

[image]

Please tell me where is fault in my code.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I've missed

`<UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo"/>` before closing of product tag. Now it worked